# Value provided is invalid for action parameter [String param] of type 'String'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller

So my component has an attribute defined like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" default="" />
```

that holds the value of a lookup `lightning:inputField`. I am setting the parameter like so:

```
createDataExport.setParams({"accountId" : component.get('v.accountId')});
```

and the backend controller looks like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String startExport(String accountId) {
```

and yet I am still getting the error `Value provided is invalid for action parameter accountId of type 'String'`. I have also tried changing over to type `Id` but no dice. I've also made sure that the attribute is populating properly, and it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to get the value of the attribute this way because an array proxy is returned by default:

```
createDataExport.setParams({"accountId" : component.get('v.accountId')[0]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the insight. I applied this to LWC.

**HTML Code:**

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="object_API_name">
<lightning-input-field 
     field-name="field_API_name" 
     value ={value} 
     onchange={handlesearch} 
     field-level-help="Search">
</lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

**JS Code**

```
handlesearch(event){
        this.property = (event.detail.value)[0];
}
```